Stacked adjectives?
If I say adjectives in a row, where the first could apply to the second, such as "cute blonde girl" - does it imply that I think blonde is cute? If it doesn't, why not and how would this be phrased to do so?

Are you trying to say you think blondes in general are cute? If so you’d need to say just that. “Blonde” is a modifier and can’t have “cuteness” of its own. “Cute blonde girl” implies a blonde girl who is cute. If you were to add a comma between them (“cute, blonde girl”), the adjectives become cooridnate, and it would imply a girl who happens to be both cute and blonde.

So I would need to specify these things separately and it is improper to not have a comma? I'm in an argument with my family member that keeps writing something along the lines of "that cute fat cat" - to me, it implies that they find the cat's fatness cute but I'm not sure there's any basis in English for this.

I would say it’s more correct not to have the comma because “blonde” as a modifier is intrinsically tied to the girl, whereas “cute” is then something you’re tacking on. All you can draw from “that cute fat cat” is that there is a fat cat and they find it cute. It could be because of the cat’s fatness, or it could just be that they find that one fat cat cute (as opposed to another fat cat, which they might find ugly). It’s up to your interpretation.

You could say "cutely blonde girl" meaning she's blonde in a cute way (adverb modifies adjective), but it doesn't sound very natural/idiomatic. On the other hand, it's not totally unreasonable to say that if two things are mentioned together the speaker/writer connects them in some way.

There's a generalized semantic precedence to stacked adjectives where ones of higher precedence are generally ordered first and most likely to describe the noun rather than the succeeding adjective. Subjective assessments like "cute" have the highest precedence in this regard.

So "cute blonde girl" strongly implies that "cute" describes "girl" and not "blonde". Same with "amazing blue sky"; this pulls strongly towards "amazing" describing "sky" and not "blue".
However, adjectives used in more objective contexts tend to pull more strongly towards describing their succeeding adjectives. So in the case of "dark blonde girl", "dark" pulls towards describing "blonde" and not "girl". That is to say, this implies a girl who has dark blonde hair, not a dark girl who has blonde hair. Context affects precedence as well; "blonde" is describing a hair color in this context and "dark" is commonly used to describe color, so "dark" pulls more strongly towards "blonde" as they're more contextually related in this case.
There's also some degree of ambiguity in all of this, but it should be safe to assume in the case of "cute blonde girl" that "cute" is describing "girl". If you want to make it absolutely clear, you can use "and" or a comma in between: "a cute and blonde girl" or "a cute, blonde girl".
If you want to describe her cuteness as bundled into her blondeness, a hyphen serves to imply a stronger relationship between the adjacent adjectives. So "cute-blonde girl" would imply that there's a stronger relationship between "cute" and "blonde", that her blonde hair is cute or that the girl's cuteness has something more specifically to do with being blonde.

'Compound adjectives' are single adjectives arising from two elements combined into a single lexeme (normally a hyphenated word) such as heart-warming, sun-dried, world-famous, full-length, two-door. 'Cute blonde girls' certainly doesn't contain a compound adjective. // 'Deep blue sea' is indeterminate between 'sea appearing deep blue' and 'deep and blue sea'. In the first interpretation, the first adjective modifies the second rather than the noun. In the second, the adjectives are coordinate (and usually separated by a comma).

@EdwinAshworth I see! My understanding of compound adjectives might be incorrect. I was under the impression that any adjacent pair of adjectives -- used as such (although often rather ambiguous as many adjs. also function as nouns) -- form compounds implicitly even with the omission of the hyphen. They can implicitly form coordinate adjectives as well even with the omission of the comma?

@EdwinAshworth I think where my confusion originated is that I was under the impression that cumulative adjectives are a subset of compound adjectives - ordered very specifically -- given how the hyphen is considered optional for compound adjectives. I also didn't realize that any pair of adjectives right next to each other without inclusion of a comma could ever be considered coordinate. I'm also wondering if "blonde girl" might be more often considered a compound noun (as in the case of "beef broth").

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

With nouns certainly , there are grey areas between open compounds and strong collocations. (And CGEL don't even recognise open compound lexemes).  // I've always seen 'the deep blue sea' as using coordinate adjectives, 'the sea deep and blue', which the 'rule' insists should have a comma. It's a rule of thumb.

@EdwinAshworth I see and thank you! I tried to edit out the parts that were the most blatantly incorrect in my answer. Is it a safe assumption that typically in a cumulative set of adjectives, that at least the subjective ones at the beginning are more likely to lack relationships with their succeeding adjectives? While I can see the ambiguity in "deep blue sea", I would assume there's a very strong weight in "beautiful blue sea" that "beautiful" implies no relation to "blue" and only to "sea", or perhaps that it leans strongly towards functioning like a coordinate: "beautiful, blue sea".

Strings of more than two adjectives are usually all modifying the noun; it's too messy using other devices. With a pair of adjectives, the key issue is whether the earlier adjective modifies the noun or the second adjective. As you say, logic often informs (even mandates) the actual situation. 'The beautiful[,] blue sea' (I'd not use a comma) gravitates, as you say, heavily towards a coordinate usage. For the alternative, 'the sea was a beautiful blue' is available. And some pairings (bright blue) are strong collocations (grading to compounds like blue-green, off-white), and can ...

be assumed to be cohesive (ie not separately modifying the noun, unlike say 'a nice little old house').

@EdwinAshworth CGEL does not recognise what you call 'open compounds' for the simple reason that a compound is a single word consisting of two (or more) bases. When written as separate words we have a syntactic construction, cf. "I have a greenhouse in my garden" (compound) vs "I live in a green house (syntactic construction).

@NedStark It's all about stacking (no punctuation) vs coordination (with punctuation). For example, "cute blonde girl" is an example of stacking, where "girl" is modified by "blonde" to give "blonde girl", and this is then modified by "cute" to give the meaning "girl who is cute by the usual standards applicable to blonde girls". By contrast "a cute, blonde girl" is an example of coordination, giving the meaning "girl who is both cute and blonde".

@Bill J CGEL does not recognise what some call 'open compounds' for the simple reason that it defines a compound as a single orthographic word consisting of two (or more) bases. But they don't have a monopoly on defining metalanuage. The existence of open and closed (and hyphenated) spelling variants makes treating say 'inkwell' and 'ink well' as other than a single lexeme silly.

@EdwinAshworth CGEL is the best and most accurate available, carrying an extensive chapter on lexical word formation. "Inkwell" is best classified as a compound noun, usually written as "inkwell", though "ink-well" is found. "Ink well" written as two separate words is a syntactic construction, a nominal consisting of modifier+head. link
